# How do you use d3 (v4) to map out several geoJson objects?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mapping, geo

I have 33 geoJson objects that represent the different boroughs of London I got from this site: http://statistics.data.gov.uk/area_collection?in_collection=http%3A%2F%2Fstatistics.data.gov.uk%2Fdef%2Fgeography%2Fcollection%2FE09

Each geoJson object has the following structure:

```
{  
   "type":"Feature",
   "properties":{  
      "gml_id":"id6268d268-5d18-4555-b9fd-fafc874cb3dc",
      "LAD15CD":"E09000001",
      "LAD15NM":"City of London",
      "LAD15NMW":null
   },
   "geometry":{  
      "type":"MultiPolygon",
      "coordinates":[  
         [  
            [  
               [  
                  -0.0967862758502,
                  51.523321274974165
               ],
               [  
                  -0.096469797431341,
                  51.522821549516344
               ],
                ... and so on
            ]
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

How can I use d3 (v4) to visualise these objects as a map?

Any help is greatly appreciated!